# Extend last observed values using na.locf for specific country/variable pairs

Tags: r, na, zoo

I need to use `na.locf` from the `zoo` package to replace NA values with the last observed value. However, I need to do this only for specific country & variable pairs. These pairs are specified logically using a seperate data frame, an example of which is shown below.

```
Country <- c("FRA", "DEU", "CHE")
acctm <- c(0, 0, 1)
acctf <- c(1, 1, 0)

df1 <- data.frame(Country, acctm, acctf)

  Country acctm acctf
1     FRA     0     1
2     DEU     0     1
3     CHE     1     0
```

a `1` meaning use `na.locf` for this pair. An example of the dataset where replacement would be needed is shown below.

```
Country <- c("FRA", "FRA", "DEU", "DEU", "CHE", "CHE")
Year <- c(2010, 2020, 2010, 2020, 2010, 2020)
acctm <- c(20, 30, 10, NA, 20, NA)
acctf <- c(20, NA, 15, NA, 40, NA)

df2 <- data.frame(Country, Year, acctm, acctf)

   Country Year acctm acctf
1      FRA 2010    20    20
2      FRA 2020    30    NA
3      DEU 2010    10    15
4      DEU 2020    NA    NA
5      CHE 2010    20    40
6      CHE 2020    NA    NA
```

Given both of the example datasets, the result of the function executing na.locf on df2 for country/variable pairs indicated by `df1` should look like this:

```
acctm <- c(20, 30, 10, NA, 20, 20)
acctf <- c(20, 20, 15, 15, 40, NA)

df3 <- data.frame(Country, Year, acctm, acctf)

  Country2 Year  acctm  acctf
1      FRA 2010     20     20
2      FRA 2020     30     20
3      DEU 2010     10     15
4      DEU 2020     NA     15
5      CHE 2010     20     40
6      CHE 2020     20     NA
```

The real application is a much larger dataset, so "calls" should be generalized. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is a join with `data.table` `on` the 'Country' column, then use `Map` to apply  the `na.locf` on the second dataset columns ('nm1') based on the value of the corresponding columns of first dataset and assign (`:=`) the output back to the columns

```
library(zoo)
library(data.table)
nm1 <- c('acctm', 'acctf')
nm2 <- paste0("i.", nm1)
setDT(df2)[df1, (nm1)  := Map(function(x, y) if(y == 1) na.locf0(x)
      else x, mget(nm1), mget(nm2)), on = .(Country), by = .EACHI]
df2
#   Country Year acctm acctf
#1:     FRA 2010    20    20
#2:     FRA 2020    30    20
#3:     DEU 2010    10    15
#4:     DEU 2020    NA    15
#5:     CHE 2010    20    40
#6:     CHE 2020    20    NA
```

Comment: I'm getting this error when trying to run on my larger dataset: `Error in [.data.table(setDT(DataMaster2), EDS, :=((AIV), Map(function(x,  : 
  Supplied 8 items to be assigned to group 71 of size 11 in column 'acctm'. The RHS length must either be 1 (single values are ok) or match the LHS length exactly. If you wish to 'recycle' the RHS please use rep() explicitly to make this intent clear to readers of your code.`

Comment: @TiberiusGracchus2020. It could be a case where the NA is at the top of some group  use `na.locf(x, na.rm = FALSE)` By default, the `na.rm = TRUE` so it could drop those elements i.e `na.locf(c(NA, NA, 3, NA, 5))` where as `na.locf(c(NA, NA, 3, NA, 5), na.rm = FALSE)#
[1] NA NA  3  3  5`

Comment: @TiberiusGracchus2020 Or another optoin is replace `na.locf` with `na.locf0` (updatedd) `na.locf0(c(NA, NA, 3, NA, 5))#
[1] NA NA  3  3  5`

Answer (score 0):

One `dplyr` and `tidyr` option could be:

```
df2 %>%
 pivot_longer(-c(Country, Year)) %>%
 left_join(df1 %>%
            pivot_longer(names_to = "cond_names", 
                         values_to = "cond_values", -Country), 
           by = c("Country" = "Country",
                  "name" = "cond_names")) %>%
 group_by(Country, name) %>%
 mutate(value = if_else(cond_values == 1, na.locf(value), value)) %>%
 select(-cond_values) %>%
 pivot_wider()

  Country  Year acctm acctf
  <fct>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 FRA      2010    20    20
2 FRA      2020    30    20
3 DEU      2010    10    15
4 DEU      2020    NA    15
5 CHE      2010    20    40
6 CHE      2020    20    NA
```

Answer (score 0):

Left join df2 to df1 on Country and then grouping by `Country` generate the appropriate value for each numeric column.  Note that we use `na.locf0` which ensures that the result has the same length as the input. Finally select the appropriate columns.

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)

df2 %>%
  left_join(df1, by = "Country") %>%
  group_by(Country) %>%
  mutate(acctm = if (first(acctm.y)) na.locf0(acctm.x) else acctm.x,
         acctf = if (first(acctf.y)) na.locf0(acctf.x) else acctf.x)  %>%
  ungroup %>%
  select(names(df2))
```

giving:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 4
  Country  Year acctm acctf
  <fct>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 FRA      2010    20    20
2 FRA      2020    30    20
3 DEU      2010    10    15
4 DEU      2020    NA    15
5 CHE      2010    20    40
6 CHE      2020    20    NA
```